# How to read a file into a weighted digraph

Tags: java

I want to implement a weighted digraph for my Assignment. I already have the code (it's a lot of code, so I can't post it here), but I want to load the text file into the graph and I'm having a hard time. My problem ist that the file has two Strings and one integer Data. Do you have any suggestions? The file is:

> - Home, Drugstore, 12
> - Home, Butcher, 6
> - Home, Lidl, 5
> - Drugstore, Home, 12
> - Drugstore, Bakery, 4
> - Butcher, Home, 6
> - Butcher, Drugstore, 8
> - Butcher, Bakery, 7
> - Lidl, Butcher, 4
> - Aldi, Drugstore, 9
> - Aldi, Bakery, 8
> - Bakery, Pharmacy, 2
> - Bakery, Edeka, 15
> - Edeka, Bakery, 15
> - Edeka, Aldi, 6
> - Edeka, Pizzeria, 5
> - Pizzeria, Bakery, 8
> - Pizzeria, Pharmacy, 9
> - Pharmacy, Pizzeria, 9
> - Pharmacy, Lidl, 6
> - Lidl, Pharmacy, 6

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    File filePath = new File("C:\\Users\\F\\Desktop\\A9\\small_town.txt");
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(filePath);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    WeightedDigraph graph = new WeightedDigraph();
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] nodes = line.split(",");
        if (nodes.length == 3){
            graph.add(nodes[0], nodes[1], Integer.parseInt(nodes[2]));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The graph:\n" + graph);
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you having a hard time with? What are the problems you encounter? Also, can you explain the need for the `if-else`? Is your input data not constistent? Also, you only `add()` on the graph inside of the `else` block, which seems like a problem. Also, `var1`, `var2`, `var3` and `w` are never used.

Comment: I want to read the text file and can't manage to do so. I just noticed but you're right. The code is extremely poorly written. I'm used to reading files with only two colums with the same data type. I get the error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:622)
 with this code.

Comment: Yeah, if you follow the error you see that `int w = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2])` is the culprit, since `tokens[]` is never filled, `nodes[]` is. You should start with removing unnecessary / dead code and variables. Think about what you really need, and remove the rest.

Comment: @maloomeister I remove all the superficial code and this is te remaining code. I still have the same error. How can I efficiently cast my third index data as integer?            
  ` WeightedDigraph graph = new WeightedDigraph();
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] nodes = line.split(",");
            if (nodes.length == 3){
                graph.add(nodes[0], nodes[1], Integer.parseInt(nodes[2]));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The graph:\n" + graph);  `

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments, as it is unreadable as you can see. Please [edit] your original question to add the updated code.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know it's works that way. I already edit my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are getting a `NumberFormatException` when parsing the split `String` to `int`. The main culprit that causes this is the whitespace inside of your `String`.

If you look at a line of your input

```
Home, Drugstore, 12
     ^          ^
```

you have whitespaces at the marked locations. These whitespaces are still part of the split strings after you do `line.split(",")` (whitespaces shown as underscores):

```
Home
_Drugstore
_12
```

And since your input to `Integer.parseInt()` then contains a whitespace, you get the aforementioned exception.

**The solution:**

a) Remove whitespaces completely when `split()`ting:

```java
line.split("\\s*,\\s*")
```

Since [`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) takes a regular expression as the input, you can provide one which splits on the comma including all whitespaces. (I would suggest this solution, since you don't really want these whitespaces in any of your `String`s after splitting)

b) Optional - Only trim the relevant string:

```java
graph.add(nodes[0], nodes[1], Integer.parseInt(nodes[2].trim()));
```

`String#trim()` removes with any leading and trailing whitespaces.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. I didn't know all of that.